# Encrypt app data on device with public/private key

Tags: android

I have an app which has 2 activities. 
The main activity has a list view of items. 
The other activity is a form to add a new item, which will later be viewed in the main activity.

Is it possible in some setup phase after first launch to generate a key pair from an entered in password and then use the public key to encrypt the form data entered in to the add item activity, and then later when viewing the items require the user to enter in the same password to decrypt the data.

I am trying to avoid storing the private key needed to decrypt the password anywhere and recreate this decryption key from the entered in password.

I am also trying to avoid having to enter in the password each time a new item is added, which is why I was hoping to use the public key to encrypt the data, as this can be stored.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why use a public/private key pair or more specifically asymmetric encryption instead of symmetric encryption such as AES? I general symmetric encryption is used to encrypt data and asymmetric encryption to encrypt symmetric keys. Asymmetric encryption is very slow and the data size is limited by the key size.

Comment: I'm my scenario could you use symmetric encryption to encrypt the newly added item without hard coding the key or asking the user to enter a password?

Comment: In any encryption the key must be available for decryption. There is a keystore on Android so that might be the place to keep it, create a random key on first use and save it in the keystore, obtain it from the keystore for encryption and decryption. Using a public/private key pair does not solve the need for a secret key. Use asymmetric encryption only when it's specific feateues are specifically needed.

Comment: If I use an encryption app like APG on Android I don't have to type in a password to encrypt a file, it's only required when I decrypt a file. This uses the public key to encrypt the file

Comment: If you don't understand the difference between and different usage scenarios between symmetric and asymmetric encryption you need to do some research. Also APG can be used with symmetric key encryption. Asymmetric (public/private key pair) encryption for data is generally incorrect and does not solve the key secrecy issue, just moves it to the private key. Good luck, there is a lot of poor security out there, a little more won't really make a real difference.

Comment: Hopefully you can understand what I am trying to achieve even if my understanding between the different encryption methods is flawed. So it would be useful to understand how to achieve the scenario I described if you have any useful pointers

Comment: Security is not easy, encryption is only a part. If you have an app that will be commercial and attract a large number of users you should get a security review and help with the security design. You also need to determine who you are protecting against and what an attackers motivation is, $$ or something else. The range is the casual teen to a well funded government. The level of security you need varies based on the potential attacks. There is no scheme that is totally secure at a reasonable price. I don't do security reviews or design for others, if the app warrants it I pay for a review.